# How to overwrite part of a png?

Tags: png

Given a png image and a set of data to write to it, is it possible to overwrite pixels in the existing png in a particular area of interest? For example, If I have a block of data in a rectangle between pixels (0,0) (5,10) would it be possible to write this data as a block into a 10X10 png without any concern for the area not being overwritten? My use case is that I have map tiles where half the data will be in one tile and half in the other, with the blank pixels being white squares. I would like to combine them by simply writing the non-white pixels directly to the existing png in a block without having to open, combine, then re-write the entire png. Does the structure of a png allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm loath to claim that this is impossible, but it is certainly complicated.

First of all, pixels of a PNG are (sometimes) [interlaced](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.6), so you'd have to calculate the locations of your target pixels based on the Adam7 scheme.

Furthermore each row is independently [filtered](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter09.html#png.ch09.div.1), so you'd have to transform each row of your source using the filter of the target row. Depending on the filter you'd also have to adjust additional bytes on the border of the updated target bytes. Straight from the horse's mouth:

> Though the concept is simple, there are quite a few subtleties in the actual mechanics of filtering.

Finally, all the filtered bytes are [compressed](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter09.html#png.ch09.div.2) using a generic compression algorithm called "deflate." Unless you want to decompress the whole thing beforehand, you need to make sure both that (1) your source data can be properly decoded and (2) the bytes near the border of the target bytes are properly compressed in the context of their new neighbors.

I'm not a compression expert, so I won't argue in more detail. One piece of good news is that the algorithm seems to preserve independence between distant regions due to its [sliding window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder) scheme: data are only compressed based on data in some preceding range, say 13,000 bytes.

If this seems at all easy to you, give it a try. If you're like me, though, you'll just decode the whole thing, overwrite the pixels as bitmap data, and encode the result.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering if it would be a time saver. It looks like its pretty complicated.

Comment: "pixels of a PNG are interlaced" They can be, but they usually aren't.

Answer (score 0):

This is practically impossible because the pixels data (after a row-by-row "filtering") is compressed with ZLIB. And it's [practically impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052961/gzip-partial-modification-and-re-compression) to change part of a compressed stream.